# Use of if in the sentence below

Tags: conjunctions

> The only thing that could change my father's prediction is if Natasha ran away with me.

What does if mean in this sentence? Would it be correct if I used “whether” or “that” instead of “if” here?

Comment: Strictly, *The only thing that **could** change my father's prediction **would be** if Natasha ran away with me.* OR *The only thing that **can** change my father's prediction is if Natasha **runs** away with me.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "whether" in place of "if" as your sentence is written, as that is used with alternative conditions, and your sentence does not contain an alternative condition. You *could* write:

> My father's prediction would depend on whether Natasha ran away with me *or not*.

You can't use "that", as this would present it as a fact that happened, and your example is talking about a hypothetical future event.

"If" is the correct conjunction to indicate something conditional, but if you really wanted to write the sentence without "if" you could instead say:

> The only thing that could change my father's prediction is *Natasha running* away with me.

Answer (score 1):

You could understand your sentence in this way:

> The fact/possibility/eventuality that Natasha would run away with me is the only thing that
> could change my father's prediction.

To simplify, it is a case of 2nd conditional:

> If Natasha ran away with me// my father's prediction would change.

Here I have omitted the phrase *the only thing* so that the structure of the sentence be more obvious.